# jQuery xmlParser to list results specified by slider or buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

I am looking to modify the way in which my xmlParser returns how many results of data. I have figured out that using:

```
:lt()
```

such as this:

```
 $(xml).find("override:lt(10)").each(function () {
```

allows me to return the first X amount of results from the xml file. What I am looking to do next is to have a set of buttons or a slider to allow the user an option to select more results to be added. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Also I have the javascript for this in the HEAD content, is this right?

EDITED AND ADDITIONAL BELOW

The full code I had originally:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xml;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../_/xml/sgr_or.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });
    function xmlParser(data) {
        xml = data;
        $('#load').fadeOut();
    $(xml).find("sgr_or").each(function () {
            var lastmod = $(this).find("lastmodified").text();
        $("#lastmodified").append(lastmod);
        });
        $(xml).find("override:lt(25)").each(function () { //lt returns the desired number of results
            sgr = $(this).attr("sgr_or");
            var location = $(this).find("location").text();
            var keyserial = $(this).find("keyserial").text();
            var datestamp = $(this).find("datestamp").text();
            var notes = $(this).find("notes").text();
            var part = $(this).find("part").text();
            var defect = $(this).find("defect").text();
            var operator = $(this).find("operator").text();
            var colour =$(this).find("colour").text();

    $("#list").append('<li><a id="'+colour+'_override" rel="external" href="#dialog-overrides" data-transition="slide"><img src="../_/images/authorisers/'+operator+'.jpg" alt="'+operator+'"><h4 id="line1info">'+keyserial+" @ "+location+'</h4><p>'+datestamp+" "+part+" "+defect+'</p></a></li>');
        $('#list').listview('refresh');
        });
    }
```

Basically I'm confused as when I removed the (data) after the function the lot stops working, I thought I understood the parser method but seemingly don't... I have played around with this and tried many things but am still unable to get it working, would you be able to explain how I get rid of the (data) and add the (var) instead?

Apologies for seeming like I know very little, I am trying to learn on the go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a select box you could have this.

**HTML**

```
<select class='select'>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
</select>
```

**Updated JS**: This code could be refactored later but try this. Solution!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var xml;

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../_/xml/sgr_or.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: xmlParser
                });
            });

            function xmlParser(data) {
                xml = data;

                $('#load').fadeOut();

                $(xml).find("sgr_or").each(function () {
                    var lastmod = $(this).find("lastmodified").text();
                    $("#lastmodified").append(lastmod);
                });

                display(25); // inital value to display
            }

    function display(val){

        var liHTML = '', sgr, location, keyserial, datestamp, notes, part, defect, operator, colour;
        $(xml).find("override:lt(" + val + ")").each(function () {
            sgr = $(this).attr("sgr_or");
            location = $(this).find("location").text();
            keyserial = $(this).find("keyserial").text();
            datestamp = $(this).find("datestamp").text();
            notes = $(this).find("notes").text();
            part = $(this).find("part").text();
            defect = $(this).find("defect").text();
            operator = $(this).find("operator").text() !== 'unknown' ? 'name_of_placeholder';
            colour =$(this).find("colour").text();
            liHTML += '<li><a id="'+colour+'_override" rel="external" href="#dialog-overrides" data-transition="slide"><img src="../_/images/authorisers/'+operator+'.jpg" alt="'+operator+'"><h4 id="line1info">'+keyserial+" @ "+location+'</h4><p>'+datestamp+" "+part+" "+defect+'</p></a></li>'
        });

        $("#list").html(liHTML).listview('refresh'); 
    }



            $('.select').on('change', function(e){
                val = e.target.value;
                display(val); // call on change
            });

    </script>
```

**NOTE**

Not the neatest but should give you an idea and help you on your way. :)

**Another update**

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/XnXhZ/)**, check the link out.

Comment: Hi dcodesmith, thanks for your time and effort - I have modified my original post as I am having trouble understanding how to implement this? I don't understand the "function getXML (val) {" part as I thought I had to have it as "function getXML (xml) {", I also assume that function name doesn't matter so long as the statements are correct for the parsing technique involved hence using xmlParser.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is limit the amount of data you get back via your ajax call or are you looking to load everything and then increase/decrease the amount of data you'd like to display on the client-side?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking to limit the amount of data, initially fetching a few records, say 25 but give the user options of 25, 50, 100, 150, ALL as there may well be several hundred records, allowing the view to load fast is what I'm after and if the user wants to then load more the view will clear / refresh when they press the given option and then be presented with the number of records corresponding to the request. I managed to get a bit further but still not working as I'd hoped and cannot clear down the view - I got the initial records stacking under the old ones, so not worth posting my code...

Comment: Hi dcodesmith, Thank you for the huge effor tyou have put into this and the JSFIDDLE works perfectly, after adding my code to the project the thing that doesn't seem to work for me is the change event, nothing seems to get called?

Comment: @Palendrone, no problem, does the jsfiddle do exactly what you want? If so, try console logging what happens on the select change event ... Log say the selected value. Could you please reply to this ASAP so we can try and wrap this up today.

Comment: On the same thought pattern and I am not getting any log messages at all from the change event... I have put console.log(val); before the display(val); line of the select change event.

Comment: Could you show me the select element HTML & jQuery code? @Palendrone

Comment: let's move this too chat :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34434/discussion-between-dcodesmith-and-palendrone)